# Android launcher crashes when I click the app drawer button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hello I am working on a android launcher everything worked on my faea f2 but when i tried to run it on my faea f1 and my moto atrix 4g when I click the app drawer button the launcher crashes LogCat shows this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.d4a.tobiasuil2/com.guillaumecendre.android.launcher.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Heres the full logicat log:

```
    01-01 18:18:30.778: E/PhonePolicy(4746): Could not preload class for phone policy: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback
01-01 18:18:37.237: E/Click event(4746): Home button tapped
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.d4a.tobiasuil2/com.guillaumecendre.android.launcher.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4765)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at com.guillaumecendre.android.launcher.Main.doLayout(Main.java:1207)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at com.guillaumecendre.android.launcher.Main.onCreate(Main.java:261)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5024)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
01-01 18:18:37.837: E/AndroidRuntime(4746):     ... 11 more
```

Main.java //code is to big to post so heres a link to it via Drive:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15xlQ3nZ0b1pBq82xopcq-htEWAmrRnqQDY5uX8gabqM/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be amazing

Thanks way in advance!

D3vs4apps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: the code is to long to post heres a link to main.java: https://docs.google.com/document/d/15xlQ3nZ0b1pBq82xopcq-htEWAmrRnqQDY5uX8gabqM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Code is to big to fit in post added link for main.java via google drive to discerption Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are doing this:

```
View v = null;

cva = new CustomViewAdapter(this, 0, apps, Settings.font, Settings.font_color, Settings.font_size, Settings.icon_size, Settings.list_style, mode);

orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (Settings.list_style == LIST_STYLE) {

    lv = (ListView) v;
    lv.setAdapter(cva);
```

You are setting `v` to be `null`, and then casting it to `ListView` (Does nothing), and then you are trying to access `setAdapter` method of a null variable, hence, there you have your `NullPointerException` on line `1207`, which is `lv.setAdapter(cva);`

Comment: so what do i need to do to fix it

Comment: Your code is huge. You should retrieve the listview you want to use via findviewbyid or inflate it.

Comment: The ListView you want to use there is the same that `private ListView lv;`?

Comment: Try removing the line `lv = (ListView) v;` and just use your ListView `lv`

Comment: The ListView you want to use is declared in xml?